# Python - Will logging happen if I don't import logging module

Tags: python, logging

When debugging a python function, I set up my logging like this:

```
import logging
logger_name = 'test.log'
log_format = "%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d -%(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(filename=logger_name,
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format = log_format, 
                    filemode='w')
```

My program consists of multiple functions that are located in separate files, so I get the logger object at each file where I take functions from using the following:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

However, when executing the function for finding out its execution time, I do not want to include my logs. Is it enough to just remove the set up of logging in the file where the main function is located? Or should I also remove `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` from each file, or should I do something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [logger main idea](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#when-to-use-logging) beside logging useful information to your console or file is to disable certains level of log easily.

To disable only the `debug` logging just set the `level=logging.DEBUG`to `level=logging.INFO` or `level=logging.WARNING`.

In that way your are keeping your log to warning when in production, and if you want to use debug, reverse it back

Comment: What if I want to remove `logging.INFO` logs too?

Comment: In that case go one level above, if you set ``level=logging.WARNING``you will catch everything except **info** and **debug**, this is the best way to keep your program clean @SayyorY